# I have to click twice on Combobox in Access2007

Tags: ms-access, combobox, click

I have a table with only a text column. Furthermore I have a form with a combobox. Now I want the combobox to requery on focus. So I add a method in vba:

```
Private Sub combobox1_GotFocus()
    With combobox1
        .RowSource = "SELECT text " + _
           "FROM tblExample " + _
           " ORDER BY text"

        .Requery
    End With

End Sub
```

When I now click on the combobox1, the dropdownlist does not open. Only when I click a second time on it, it opens. What is the problem here? If I put the two .-lines in comment, I can click the combobox just one time and an empty list shows up.

Notice: I simplified the problem. I have another formular in which I do the same and it works fine. I hope someone has an idea how to fix this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply a query that is similar to t he one you are actually using. What do you need to change about the query? A where clause?

Comment: Yes, its a query with an INNER JOIN and a where clause like "SELECT tblAnotherExample.text FROM tblExample INNER JOIN tblAnotherExample ON tblExample.ID=tblAnotherExample.ExampleID WHERE tblAnotherExample.column1=" + CStr(Me.AnotherCombobox.Value) + " ORDER BY tblAnotherExample.text"

Answer (score 0):

When you requery a combo box, it temporarily loses focus. When you click on it again, it already has the focus, so the `OnFocus` event does not fire. You may want to requery the combo box before the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your OnFocus action is just fine but you could add something like this one as well.

```
Private Sub combobox1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  Me.combobox1.SetFocus
  Me.combobox1.Dropdown
End Sub
```